# Is it possible to change the colour of the Terminal Window in Visual Studio 2022 to match that of the "Package Manager Console"?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

The bright white of the terminal window in Visual Studio 2022 is harsh on the eyes, but the window for "Package Manager Console" has a muted grey background which is easy on the eye.

I can't seem to find the color element for the terminal window in the "Environment\Fonts and Colors" section.

Does anyone know if a setting for that exists who could point it out to me?

Comment: I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73431538/visual-studio-2022-change-colour-of-the-positioning-area-in-the-vertical-scroll/73436973#73436973) that might have an option for you to set the color of that.  I haven't personally looked, but basically its an extension that allows you to create your own themes.  It has A LOT more color options than native Visual Studio.  Short answer: install the extension, choose your base theme, and then search through the hundreds of options until you find the right one (that's the hard part to be honest).  Save your theme, then apply it

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't mean the ones that spawn from a Command Prompt program, but the actual Visual Studio tool window that you get by going to View\Terminal, and it is bright white not the grey of the "Package Manager Console"

Comment: ["Under review"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Terminal-window-should-allow-changing-co/811502?space=8&q=terminal+colors), consider voting for it.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for finding that, voted.  Nice to see I can do so as a few weeks ago I couldn't get to add any info to my outstanding help requests in developercommunity