# How to Change Active Item Highlight Color in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2022, solution-explorer

How do I change the Highlighted Active Item in the Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio 2022?  Operating system is Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, Visual Studio does not appear to have an option to change this. However, you can change this if you install an extension called [Visual Studio Color Theme Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner). I've gone over how to use this extension [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73436973/6530134) but in short, you will need to create a VSTheme project, select a base theme, and then change the properties of the controls you want to change.

Once you set it up, find the following controls:

Under All Elements → Tree View:

- `SelectedItemActive` (the first one which is for the background)
- `SelectedItemActive` (the second one, which is for the foreground/text)

After you find these two, change the color of them to whatever you desire, and apply the theme.  You may also want to change `SelectedItemInactive` (again, there are two where one is for the background, and the other is for the foreground).

You can see here that I've changed mine to a bright green with blue text:

[image: solution explorer showing highlighted item with a green background and blue foreground]

Note that this will also change similar windows that use a "tree view" since it is a shared property between the various windows (for example, Server Explorer will also inherit these settings).

Comment: Thank you!  This is the only thing that has worked for me.  It's a lot of effort to go to, but I'm very happy I can now change the Selected Item Inactive colour to one that I can actually see.